# Creating a website as a co-administrator?

Tags: azure

I'm trying to create a WordPress site from the gallery, but I don't have the option to select a subscription that I know I'm a co-administrator of. If I go to the old portal, I can see that I am a co-administrator of another subscription, but I cannot select that account when creating a new website.

I *can* see the subscription I want to use if I create a Cloud Service and a few other types, but I do not see the right subscription when I try to create a website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to be able to create an Azure WebSite (as well as Virtual Machine, Media Service and Mobile Service) you need to enable first that Preview Feature. And only the administrator can opt-in for enabling the Preview Features of a subscriptions. They are not enabled by default. The account administrator can do it from the Windows Azure site (http://www.windowsazure.com/) -> Account section -> Account Center -> Preview Features. It may take some time before the features are activated.

Comment: @AlexDresko An upvote is more valuable than a comment, so why not do both :)